# Rails: CarrierWave resize_to_ don't working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, rmagick

I use CarrierWave to upload file (image)

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_limit => [600, 240]
  end

  version :large do
    process :resize_to_limit => [960, 360]
  end
end
```

In my model

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :banner, ImageUploader
end
```

When i upload a image with original size [1006, 368]
after upload 
i have 3 version of image above (original, banner and medium), but both 3 version same size [1006, 368]. Should 3 version have 3 different size.
How do i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with MiniMagick

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_limit => [600, 240]
  end

  version :large do
    process :resize_to_limit => [960, 360]
  end
end
```

Also check following link for details

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave%2FMiniMagick%3Aresize_to_limit

also needs to add `gem "mini_magick"` in Gemfile

Comment: No no, i use method resize_to_limit, it method belong Rmagick
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/RMagick#resize_to_limit-instance_method

and when i try resize_to_fill and resize_to_fit , both method occur are similar

Comment: ohh got it , can you please try to include MiniMagick and give a try

Comment: can you please check that  resize_to_limit(100, 100) syntax work for you?